# How to catch exeption of undefined variable from wmic command in FOR cycle?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have some code which get videoadapter name and correct memory size.

```
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Setlocal EnableExtensions

rem | Get VideoAdapters Name and Device ID
FOR /F "skip=2 tokens=2,3 delims=," %%a IN ('wmic path win32_VideoController get name^, PNPDeviceID /format:csv') DO (
IF NOT DEFINED %%a (ECHO No driver >> D:\004.txt) ELSE (ECHO Something else >> D:\004.txt)
IF %%a LSS 1 (ECHO No driver >> D:\004.txt) ELSE (ECHO Something else >> D:\004.txt)
SET vc_name=%%a
IF NOT DEFINED !vc_name! (ECHO No driver >> D:\004.txt) ELSE (ECHO Something else >> D:\004.txt)
IF !vc_name! LSS 1 (ECHO No driver >> D:\004.txt) ELSE (ECHO Something else >> D:\004.txt)
IF %%vc_name%% LSS 1 (ECHO No driver >> D:\004.txt) ELSE (ECHO Something else >> D:\004.txt)

SET vc_name=%%a
IF "vc_name"=="" (ECHO vc_name not defined >> D:\004.txt) ELSE (ECHO Something strange >> D:\004.txt)

rem | Get Device ID and filter out
FOR /F "tokens=2 delims=^&amp;" %%c IN ("%%b") DO (

rem | Search in registry for key where device ID is stored
FOR /F %%d IN ('REG QUERY HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E968-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318} /f %%c /s /t REG_SZ ^| find "{"') DO (

rem | Search for correct memory size in the same regisrty key where was found device id
FOR /F "tokens=3" %%e IN ('REG QUERY ^"%%d^" /f HardwareInformation.qwMemorySize /t REG_QWORD ^| find "0x"') DO (
SET vc_mem=powershell [uint64]^('%%e'^)/1048576
)
)
)
:L6
rem | Write video adapter name in file
ECHO !vc_name!^ >> %~dp0%computername%.txt

rem | Write memory in file
rem | Also chesk if memory qwMemorySize defined in registry 
rem | If not it means we have integrated gpu
IF !vc_mem! LSS 1 (SET vc_mem=DVMT&ECHO !vc_mem! >> %~dp0%computername%.txt) ELSE (!vc_mem! >> %~dp0%computername%.txt&ECHO Mb >> %~dp0%computername%.txt)
)

pause
```

Code works fine, but I can not cath exception when drivers for GPU not installed and command

```
wmic path win32_VideoController get Name, PNPDeviceID
```

return

```
No Instance(s) Available
```

As you can see above I tryed to catch if %%a variable or vc_name variable are not defined or empty in any way possible, yet I got zero results. File 004.txt is blank when no GPU Drivers Installed in system. I need help in figuring out how to catch this exception - when no drivers installed for GPU. Thank you.

UPD: Code suggested by aschipfl does not seem to work.

```
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion EnableExtensions

FOR /F "tokens=*" %%i IN ('wmic path win32_VideoController get name') DO (
IF "%%i"=="" (ECHO i is NOT defined >> %~dp0%computername%.txt) ELSE (ECHO i is DEFINED >> %~dp0%computername%.txt)
)

pause
```

On system with drivers installed the output is:

```
i is DEFINED 
i is DEFINED 
i is DEFINED
```

And it is OK, since driver installed. But on system with NO driver installed the same code output is:

```
i is DEFINED 
i is DEFINED
```

Comment: Why have you got an `:L6` label within your outer `FOR /F` loop? It doesn't seem to be used, and will be problematic if you intend to use it too. You should not use labels within a `For` loop. Also, what is `IF NOT DEFINED %%a` supposed to do? Have you already defined some variables containing some VideoController names? I would assume not, and therefore you will always see `No driver` written to `D:\004.txt` from that line!

Comment: When I think again about problem, I say to myself: Why not check driver existence BEFORE cycle. It seems most elegant and simple solution. Thank you. Oh, well, L6 was supposed to be used to skip inner cycles if vc_name is not defined. Script must redefine vc_name=NoDriverInstalled in that case and jump straight to th end of main cycle

Comment: UPD: It seems that problem is that when wmic return "No instance(s) Available" cycle FOR is interrupted, or more correctly, it even does not start. Because code like ```Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%i IN ('wmic path win32_VideoController get name ^| find ""') DO (
SET vc_name=%i 
ECHO variable name is %vc_name% >> C:\Users\user\Desktop\004.txt
)
``` return only ```No Instance(s) Available.``` So it is clear now, that cycle is interrupted.

Comment: `IF NOT DEFINED %%a` cannot work, you need to use `if "%%a"==""` instead. Neither can work `IF NOT DEFINED !vc_name!`, which should read `if not defined vc_name`, because `if [not] defined` expects the *name* of an *environment* variable…